# Is Tensorflow Dataset.from_generator deprecated in tensorflow 2.0 ? It throws tf.py_func deprecation error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

When I create a tf dataset from generator and try to run tf2.0 code , It warns me with a deprication message.

Code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model


def my_function():
    import numpy as np
    for i in range(1000):
        yield np.random.random(size=(28, 28, 1)), [1.0]


train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(my_function, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32)).batch(32)


class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.d2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        return self.d2(x)

    # def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     return super().__call(*args,**kwargs)


model = MyModel()

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')


@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(images)
        loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(labels, predictions)


EPOCHS = 5

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for images, labels in train_ds:
        train_step(images, labels)
    template = 'Epoch {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}'
    print(template.format(epoch + 1,
                          train_loss.result(),
                          train_accuracy.result() * 100))
```

Warning message:

```
........
Instructions for updating:
tf.py_func is deprecated in TF V2. Instead, there are two
    options available in V2. ........
```

I would like to feed data to model from a streaming input using dataset API (with prefetch ). Even though it's still possible in the current alpha release, will it be removed later on?

Will tensorflow replace tf.py_func used in generator dataset to something new or will the entire dataset_from generator API be removed ?

Answer (score 3):

No, [tf.data.Dataset.from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) won't be deprecated in TensorFlow 2.0. What you see is a warning message, it's used to inform users about future changes. In case you need to use py_func directly, the most straightforward way is to use `tf.compat.v1.py_func`. TF2.0 has it's own wrapper, called `tf.py_function`.

Comment: I don't want to use tf.py_func function. Dataset.from_generator function internally is using py_func. Will they replace this implementation to something else?. I just want to know if from_generator is future proof (at least for the near future).

Comment: It is included in TF 2.0. I guess the'll replace py_func in later, stable release